# Выбрать записи с максимальными значениями столбцов

Tags: mysql

Как выбрать записи с максимальными значениями столбцов?
Например у меня есть таблица:

```
    id                 name                     rating
1                    Компьютеры                    4
2                    Ноутбуки                      7
3                    Разное                        8
4                    Компьютеры 1                  6     
5                    Компьютеры 2                  9  
6                    Компьютеры 1.1                2  
7                    Ноутбуки 1                    1
8                    Ноутбуки 2                    3
```

Надо вывести 3 записи у которых rating самый большой

В примере должно вывести записи с id - 5,3,2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 0,3
```